# How to format html table with inline styles to look like a rendered Excel table?

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

I'm currently stuck setting borders in an html table. (I use inline styles for a better rendering in e-mail-clients) I have this piece of code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td width="350" style="border: 1px solid black ;">
                    Foo
                </td>
                <td width="80" style="border: 1px solid black ;">
                    Foo1
                </td>
                <td width="65" style="border: 1px solid black ;">
                    Foo2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Bar1
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Bar2
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Bar3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Bar1
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Bar2
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Bar3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is rendered like this:
[image]

I want the table to be rendered like Excel would render a table, with inner and outer border:
[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using? in Chrome 6, looks as you want it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JceAc/.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 42):

This is quick-and-dirty (and not formally valid HTML5), but it seems to work -- and it is *inline* as per the question:

```
<table border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse'>
```

No further styling of `<tr>`/`<td>` tags is required (for a basic table grid).

Comment: I was looking for this. All other answers are with `style`, only this one is for `inline'. Thanks!

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. As question is clearly about inline style.

Comment: To make it look reasonably tidy, you may want additional styling like: `<style>th,td { padding: 4px; }</style>`

Comment: I discovered a very strange and sometimes annoying feature of tables. The text is auto-resized to fit the width of the page when printing. A side-effect of this is that using larger paper (or printing landscape) does not allow you to fit more information on a sheet of paper. The fix was to set _both_ of `th, td` to a specific font size (as a `style`): `@media print { th, td { font-size: 10pt; } }`

Comment: Although this solution seems to work for now, the use of the [`HTMLTableElement.border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/border) property seems to be deprecated -- so it may stop working in 1000 years. An _inline_ alternative, albeit more verbose, may be to apply [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) styling to individual [table data cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) and [table header cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th).

Answer (score 12):

Add cellpadding and cellspacing to solve it.
Edit: Also removed double pixel border.

```
<style>
td
{border-left:1px solid black;
border-top:1px solid black;}
table
{border-right:1px solid black;
border-bottom:1px solid black;}
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="350" >
                    Foo
                </td>
                <td width="80" >
                    Foo1
                </td>
                <td width="65" >
                    Foo2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bar2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bar3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td>
                    Bar1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bar2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Bar3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```